# Executing an exe file using php on server error

Tags: php, server, exe

I am trying to run an exe file on server to display it for user. I have an exe file uploaded on my server. I have created an index.php file and gave the following code:

```html
<?php

// index.php

echo $_GET['cmd'];?>
```

Now I am calling it through my url like

> demo.com/index.php?=C:\path\AUTORUN.exe

Which gives me blank page. Can anyone please tell me why my exe is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access `$_GET['cmd']` you need to pass in request parameter with that name. In your case something like: `demo.com/index.php?cmd=C:\path\AUTORUN.exe`
Also: running application from request parameters is really bad from security point of view.

Comment: the app is not running, instead its displaying C:\path\AUTORUN.exe

Comment: i guess you didnt understand what i said. i want to run the app on server. Your answer is just dispkaying the path which i give in url

Comment: To run an external app from PHP you can use `exec` or `cmd` functions like `exec($_GET['cmd'])`. And please consider security while doing that.